# Chunk list into lists of consecutive identical objects

Tags: kotlin

Say I have a function that collects a list of characters into lists of all consecutive identical characters:

```
 [a, a, b, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, c] -> [[a, a], [b], [a], [b, b, b], [c, c, c, c]]
```

My solution here would be to manually populate an ArrayList as such:

```
fun foo(chars: List<Char>): List<List<Char>> {
    val result = arrayListOf<ArrayList<Char>>()
    var part = arrayListOf(chars.first())
    var cur = chars.first()
    for (char in chars.drop(1)){
        if (cur == char) part.add(char)
        else {
            cur = char
            result.add(part)
            part = arrayListOf(char)
        }
    }
    if(part.isNotEmpty()) result.add(part)
    return result
}
```

This seems horribly inelegant, however, so I am thinking there must be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a build-in function that could handle this problem neatly. Well, you might try with `fold` maybe, but still you'd probably end up with something that could be less understandable than your current solution. What I'd suggest is create an extension function `fun List<Char>.foo(): List<List<Char>>`, which would allow you to execute the inelegant solution in an elegant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` [function][1]:

```
val chars = listOf('a', 'a', 'b', 'a')

val result = chars.groupBy { it } // Map<Char,List<Char>> = ['a' to ['a','a'], 'b' to ['b']]
```

If you want a list of lists afterwards, just use `result.values`

EDIT

Thanks for pointing out, that the answer should countain not all groups but the consequtive ones. The solution for this is a bit longer:

```
val chars = listOf('a', 'a', 'b', 'a')

val result = chars.fold(mutableListOf<Char>() to mutableListOf<List<Char>>()) { (currentList, allLists), currentItem ->

    if (currentList.isEmpty()) { // Applies only to the very first item
        mutableListOf(currentItem) to allLists
    } else {

        if (currentItem == currentList.first()) { // same char
            currentList.apply { add(currentItem) } to allLists
        } else {
            mutableListOf(currentItem) to allLists.apply { add(currentList) } // Next
        }

    }
}
    .let { it.second.apply { add(it.first) } } //Convert to List<List<Char>> and add last remaining list
```

Comment: Close, unfortunately not quite what I was looking for as this will group all identical Chars into lists, not only consecutive ones: 
`[a, a, b, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, c] -> [[a, a, a], [b, b, b, b], [c, c, c, c]]`

Answer (score 1):

as an option, converts in one single line

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val list = arrayListOf('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
    val result = "(\\w)\\1*".toRegex().findAll(list.joinToString("")).map { it.value.toCharArray() }.toList()

    for (arr in result) {
        print(arr.contentToString()) // prints [a, a][b][a][b, b, b][c, c, c, c]
    }

}
```

Comment: I was looking for a more generic solution, but I suppose I didn't really specify that. Regex is a really smart solution to this problem. One tip though: instead of `"(\\w)\\1*".toRegex()` you could use `Regex("(\\w)\\1*")`

Comment: i think it will inlined exactly into Regex("bla bla") so it's the same

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be best achieved in a more reusable manner with a `chunk` implementation that is using an indicator function:

```
fun <T, I> List<T>.chunked(chunkIndicator: (T) -> I): List<List<T>> {
    val underlyingSequence = this
    return buildList {
        val buffer = mutableListOf<T>()
        var lastPredicate: I? = null

        for (current in underlyingSequence) {
            val curPredicate = chunkIndicator(current)
            if(lastPredicate != curPredicate) {
                add(buffer.toList())
                buffer.clear()
            }
            buffer.add(current)
            lastPredicate = curPredicate
        }
        if (buffer.isNotEmpty()) {
            add(buffer)
        }
    }
}
```

With the generic utility, we can express the use case from the question as

```
listOf("a", "a", "b", "a", "c").chunked{ it }

// other example: chunk by first letter
listOf("ab", "ac", "ba", "aa", "c").chunked{ it[0] }
```